# Discord JS - If the user reacting to message has a specific role I want to add a role

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm attempting to create a more complex reaction role function.

Basically I want to achieve that if a user has 2 roles, it should have access to some channels.
So the way I'm trying to do this is by checking if the user has one of the roles when clicking on a reaction that grants the member the second role. If the user has the other role, he should get a third role that unlocks these channels.

But, I haven't been able to figure out how to look at the roles of the person reacting to the message.

```
    client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  const message = await reaction.message.fetch(true);
  const channelAccess = '918617193988649002';
  const foodSweden = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '');
  const foodCategoryReaction = '';
    if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if (user.bot) return;
    if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
    if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelAccess) {
      if (reaction.emoji.name === foodCategoryReaction && message.member.roles.has('')) {
        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(foodSweden);
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
  });
```

So this is the code. I'm uncertain how `message.member.roles.has('')` should be coded.
I've tried `reaction.message.member.roles.has('')`, `reaction.member.roles.has('')`, `user.roles.has('')` and shifted out member for user.

Comment: It probably goes without saying. But if anyone could help me out, I'd really, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm uncertain how message.member.roles.has('') should be coded. I've tried reaction.message.member.roles.has(''), reaction.member.roles.has(''), user.roles.has('') and shifted out member for user.

None of those are existing methods. `member.roles` does not have a `.has()` method. And users represent general discord users outside of guilds; users do not have roles, only guild members have roles. The `.has()` method of any manager in discord.js also usually utilizes IDs (which is what they are mapped to in the underlying `Collection` cache), not names or other properties. See the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager).

Here is how you check if the member who reacted has a specific role:

```js
const hasRole = reaction.message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name == "");
```

The role cache for guild members is almost always up-to-date, so you don't really need to do any fetching. You can rely on the role cache here.

Comment: This is gold. Thanks Cannicide!